# jQuery UI Accent Map file

Tags: jquery-ui

Anyone know of a publically available accent map file that I can use with jQuery UI AutoComplete with Accent Folding ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#folding ) ? It should contain common variations of the same accents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/accent-folding-for-auto-complete/)? Actual map is at the top of this file:
https://github.com/aristus/accent-folding/blob/master/accent-fold.js

Comment: Sweet! .Thank you. Sorry for the late reply but I completely forgot about this question.